# Is it possible to add artisan to my path so I don't have to prepend artisan commands with 'php'

Tags: laravel, path, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

When I SSH into homestead, I no longer need to prepend my artisan commands with `php`. ie. I can write, for example

```
artisan -h
```

rather than

```
php artisan -h
```

But on my local machine, I always have to first issue the command through php. How is it that this is not necessary within homestead, and is there a way to replicate this behaviour on my local machine. I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer really depends on what OS you're running locally. On macOS / Linux, you can edit (or create) a `.bash_aliases` file in your user folder and add the line:

```
alias artisan='php artisan'
```

You can see this in action by running the following command in homestead:

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: Aliases. of course! Thanks for the pointer- so in Windows 7, I added the line `alias artisan='php artisan'` to the end of my `.bash_profile` file in my user directory. It works!